# How do I get boot to work correctly after deleting Ubuntu partitions?

Tags: 12.04, boot, windows-xp

So, recently, I got this old computer. I put Windows XP on it, and that was fine, but last name I put Ubuntu 12.04 on it, but some error about the graphics came up, so I assumed the graphics was just too old. I was planning on removing Ubuntu 12.04 and then maybe installing an older version, or just not getting it. Well, I've never removed Ubuntu off a computer before, so I just assumed that you delete the partitions Ubuntu was on. Apparently not. Now, when I start up the computer, I get command line-like prompt that is something like 'grub>' and says 'filesystem not recognized' or something like that.
How do I get it to boot on Windows XP again?

Answer (score 0):

Try Boot-Repir:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
Try the "recommended" (default) button first. Advanced options explained on the website if the default settings won't work.

Good Luck!